# A custom view in between table view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I wish to display a custom view in between a table view if a particular cell's attribute matches some condition.
Something like this
Row 1 
Row 2 
 
Row (n) (matches condition)
--------------------------- (Custom View)
Row (n+1) 
Row (n+2)

I am using a TableView and TableViewDelegate in a ViewController

Comment: Why not use a Table View Cell as the custom view?

Comment: That cell is a custom view. Since that view is generic and is separated by some space so I cannot add that custom view in the cell view.

Comment: @dasdom Now i got what you wanted to say. If you had elaborated more and posted it as an answer, I would've accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need TableDataSource with the delegate. The just return another cell class, depending on the condition of the object in source array in the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: method of the table delegate.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

MyObjectClass * objectFromArray = [sourceArray.objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

if(condition on MyObjectClass or index row){
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

return cell;
}
}else{
static NSString *MyOtherIdentifier = @"MyOtherReuseIdentifier";
    NewUITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NewUITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyOtherIdentifier];
    }

return cell;
}
}

}
```